# Compare Multiple Columns to Get Rows that are Different in Two Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
df1=
    A    B   C
0   A0   B0  C0
1   A1   B1  C1
2   A2   B2  C2

df2=
    A    B   C
0   A2   B2  C10
1   A1   B3  C11
2   A9   B4  C12
```

and I want to find rows in df1 that are not found in df2 based on one or two columns (or more columns). So, if I only compare column 'A' then the following rows from df1 are not found in df2 (note that column 'B' and column 'C' are not used for comparison between df1 and df2)

```
    A    B   C
0   A0   B0  C0
```

And I would like to return a series with

```
0   False
1   True
2   True
```

Or, if I only compare column 'A' and column 'B' then the following rows from df1 are not found in df2 (note that column 'C' is not used for comparison between df1 and df2)

```
    A    B   C
0   A0   B0  C0
1   A1   B1  C1
```

And I would want to return a series with

```
0   False
1   False
2   True
```

I know how to accomplish this using sets but I am looking for a straightforward Pandas way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 4):

If your version is `0.17.0` then you can use [`pd.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge) and pass the cols of interest, how='left' and set `indicator=True` to whether the values are only present in left or both. You can then test whether the appended `_merge` col is equal to 'both':

```
In [102]:
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='A',how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'] == 'both'

Out[102]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: _merge, dtype: bool

In [103]:
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B'],how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'] == 'both'

Out[103]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: _merge, dtype: bool
```

output from the merge:

```
In [104]:
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='A',how='left', indicator=True)

Out[104]:
    A B_x C_x  B_y  C_y     _merge
0  A0  B0  C0  NaN  NaN  left_only
1  A1  B1  C1   B3  C11       both
2  A2  B2  C2   B2  C10       both

In [105]:    
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B'],how='left', indicator=True)

Out[105]:
    A   B C_x  C_y     _merge
0  A0  B0  C0  NaN  left_only
1  A1  B1  C1  NaN  left_only
2  A2  B2  C2  C10       both
```

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, one would like to be able to just use ~df1[COLS].isin(df2[COLS]) as a mask, but this requires index labels to match (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Here is a succinct form that uses .isin but converts the second DataFrame to a dict so that index labels don't need to match:

```
COLS = ['A', 'B'] # or whichever columns to use for comparison

df1[~df1[COLS].isin(df2[COLS].to_dict(
    orient='list')).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 ~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])
```

Should get you the series you want

```
df1[ ~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])]
```

The dataframe:

```
    A   B   C
0   A0  B0  C0
```

Comment: Thats a bit more complicated. I didnt realize you wanted to dynamically deal witgh a variable number of columns. I can get to it later if someone else cant help you till then

Comment: With more than one column the index labels need to match as well - so it's a bit more tricky.

Answer (score 1):

### Method ( 1 )

---

```
In [63]:
df1['A'].isin(df2['A']) & df1['B'].isin(df2['B'])
Out[63]:

0   False
1   False
2   True
```

### Method ( 2 )

---

you can use the left merge to obtain values that exist in both frames `+` values that exist in the first data frame only

```
In [10]:
left = pd.merge(df1 , df2 , on = ['A' , 'B'] ,how = 'left')
left
Out[10]:
    A   B   C_x C_y
0   A0  B0  C0  NaN
1   A1  B1  C1  NaN
2   A2  B2  C2  C10
```

then of course values that exist only in the first frame will have `NAN` values in columns of the other data frame , then you can filter by this `NAN` values by doing the following

```
In [16]:
left.loc[pd.isnull(left['C_y']) , 'A':'C_x']
Out[16]:
    A   B   C_x
0   A0  B0  C0
1   A1  B1  C1

In [17]:
```

if you want to get whether the values in `A` exists in `B` you can do the following

```
In [20]:
pd.notnull(left['C_y'])
Out[20]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: C_y, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a better way to represent Method #1 when there are more and more columns

Comment: better in terms of what ?

Comment: Length of the code. As it stands, one would need to keep adding `&` in order to add more columns. It would be better if it could be wrapped into, say, a list comprehension (or apply function) since each column is independent