# Update Dataframe conditionally based on values in another Dataframe with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine 2 Dataframes, where MasterDB (df1) is a Central Database and LatestResults (df2) is an incoming CSV I retrieve weekly.

```
df1 = pd.read_sv("Master.csv")
#with columns:
Index(['Timestamp', 'ID', 'Status', 'Username', 'URL', 'Last Seen'], 
      dtype='object')
Shape(1000,6)

df2 = pd.read_sv("LatestResults.csv") 
#with same columns:
Index(['Timestamp', 'ID', 'Status', 'Username', 'URL', 'Last Seen'], 
      dtype='object')
Shape(300,6)
```

Based on certain conditions, I would like to iterate through my (new) items in df2 and treat items based on the following 3 conditions (assuming there's only 3 for now):

a) if new item does not pre-exist (for non-matching "URL")

- append to MasterDB (df1)
- set 'Status' = "Net New" (in df1)
- set 'Last Seen' = today.date (in df1)

b) if new item pre-exists, edit its status to "Still Active" (for matching "URL", regardless of "ID")

- set 'Status' to "Still Active"
- set 'Last Seen' = today.date

c) if item in MasterDB (df1) is not found in LatestResults (only for matching "ID" AND "URL")

- set 'Status to 'Expired'

Here's the code I have so far:

```
def function(input1, input2):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(input1)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(input2)
    df1['Status'] = df1['Status'].astype(str)
    df1['Last Seen'] = df1['Last Seen'].astype(str)

    for i, row in df1.iterrows():
        tmp = df2.loc[(df2['URL'] == row['URL'])
        
        # A) STILL ACTIVE 
        if not tmp.empty:
            df1.at[i, 'Last Seen'] = str(datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0))
            df1.at[i, 'Status'] = "STILL ACTIVE"

    for i, row in df1.iterrows():
        tmp = df2.loc[(df2['URL'] == row['URL']) & (df2['ID'] == row['ID'])]

        # B) NOT FOUND // EXPIRED 
        if tmp.empty:
            df1.at[i, 'Status'] = "EXPIRED"

    for i, row in df2.iterrows():
        tmp = df1.loc[(df1['URL'] == row['URL']) & (df1['ID'] == row['ID'])]
        
        # C) NET NEW
        if tmp.empty:
            df1.at[i, 'Last Seen'] = str(datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0))
            row["Status"] = "NET NEW"
            df1 = df1.append(row, ignore_index=True)

    df1['Last Seen'].fillna("Not Set", inplace=True)
    df1.to_csv("MasterDB.csv", index=False)
```

This solution works for the most part. New items are appended and (some) pre-existing items are labeled correctly. The problems I'm having are:

1. When matching still active records, if the item is untouched (most cases), its value is overwritten to NaN. How can I fix this?
2. For my third case "Expired", I want to be severe with the and conditions and only set to expired if both conditions are met. It does not seem to work. Is this the right way to think of it?

I've explored using pandas merge, join and map but persevered using the methods here above. But after a few days on this, I realize it's bulky. I'd love to hear ideas about how to design this differently. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to share with you how I would implement a solution for your problem. Perhaps a different point of view can help you see what's wrong in your code.

First, the data that I used. This is my `LatestResults.csv`

```
   ID Status          Username        URL            Last Seen
0   1    new      Harry Potter     google  2020-10-20 12:00:00
1  20    new  Hermione Granger      yahoo  2020-10-20 12:00:00
2   3    new       Ron Weasley    twitter  2020-10-20 12:00:00
3   4    new            Hagrid  instagram  2020-10-20 12:00:00
```

And this is my `MasterDB.csv`

```
   ID  Status          Username       URL            Last Seen
0   1  blabla      Harry Potter    google  2020-10-20 12:00:00
1   2  blabla  Hermione Granger     yahoo  2020-10-20 12:00:00
2   3  blabla       Ron Weasley      bing  2020-10-20 12:00:00
3   4  blabla        McGonagall  facebook  2020-10-20 12:00:00
4   5  blabla        Dumbledore    google  2020-10-20 12:00:00
5   6  blabla      You-Know-Who     badoo  2020-10-20 12:00:00
```

I tried to include all possible combinations:

- `Harry Potter` has the same `ID` and `URL` in both DataFrames
- `Hermione Granger` has the same `URL`, but different `ID`
- `Ron Weasley` has the same `ID`, but different `URL`
- `McGonagall` has a unique `URL`, but the same `ID` as `Hagrid`
- `Dumbledore` has a unique `ID`, but the same `URL` as `Harry Potter`
- `You-Know-Who` has uniques `ID` and `URL`
- `Hagrid` has a unique unique `URL`, but it's not in you database yet

I know the `username` is not used anywhere in the code, but these names help us to understand what's going on.

Now the code.

```
def new_function(db_file, input_file):
    today = datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
    df_input = pd.read_csv(input_file)
    df_database = pd.read_csv(db_file)
    df_database['Last Seen'].astype(str)

    # Filter for input data
    net_new_filter = ~ df_input['URL'].isin(df_database['URL'])

    # Filter for DB data
    still_active = df_database['URL'].isin(df_input['URL'])
    expired_filter = (pd.merge(df_database, df_input, on=['ID', 'URL'],
                           how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'] != 'both')
    expired_filter = expired_filter & (~ still_active)

    # Applying filters
    df_database.loc[still_active, 'Status'] = 'Still Active'
    df_database.loc[still_active, 'Last Seen'] = str(today)
    df_database.loc[expired_filter, 'Status'] = 'Expired'

    new_data = df_input[net_new_filter].copy()
    new_data['Status'] = 'Net New'
    new_data['Last Seen'] = str(today)

    final_database = pd.concat([df_database, new_data],
                               ignore_index=True)

    final_database.to_csv("Test_Data/Output.csv", index=False)
```

I enjoy writing DataFrame filters separately since it makes clearer what conditions you are applying.

You may use the method `.isin()` to verify if the elements of a column are located somewhere in another column. It directly detects the "Still Active" and the "Net New" conditions.

Then, if you want to check if two columns of the same row are equal two other columns simultaneously, you may use the `.merge()` method, such as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33524251/14298880). However, we must not overwrite the "Still Active" condition, therefore the additional expression `expired_filter = expired_filter & (~ still_active)`.

Once you run the code, the following DataFrame will be saved:

```
   ID        Status          Username        URL            Last Seen
0   1  Still Active      Harry Potter     google  2020-10-23 20:18:00
1   2  Still Active  Hermione Granger      yahoo  2020-10-23 20:18:00
2   3       Expired       Ron Weasley       bing  2020-10-20 12:00:00
3   4       Expired        McGonagall   facebook  2020-10-20 12:00:00
4   5  Still Active        Dumbledore     google  2020-10-23 20:18:00
5   6       Expired      You-Know-Who      badoo  2020-10-20 12:00:00
6   3       Net New       Ron Weasley    twitter  2020-10-23 20:18:00
7   4       Net New            Hagrid  instagram  2020-10-23 20:18:00
```

The rows with new `URL` are at the end, while those from the original database which didn't have an exact match over `ID` and `URL` were set to "Expired". Finally, the rows with corresponding `URL` were kept, and their `Status` was set to "Still Active".

I hope this example helps you out. At least it's a little bit faster because it doesn't rely on `for` loops.

If the data wasn't helpful, please provide a sample of your own data, so we can test using the same dataset.

Comment: This is it, and it makes so much more sense now! The masks you create make it so much easier to manage, and faster without having to iterate with for loops. Infinite thanks for taking the time and explaining this so easily. I also realized my input file can be structured better to be more selective on expired items conidtions. Thanks again!